# DeSerializing JSON returns null C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I have following JSON that I'm trying to deserialize.

```
{  
"output-parameters":[  
  {  
     "value":{  
        "array":{  
           "elements":[  
              {  
                 "string":{  
                    "value":"cp-100"
                 }
              },
              {  
                 "string":{  
                    "value":"cp-101"
                 }
              },
              {  
                 "string":{  
                    "value":"cp-100"
                 }
              },
              {  
                 "string":{  
                    "value":"cp-101"
                 }
              },
              {  
                 "string":{  
                    "value":"cp-100"
                 }
              }
           ]
        }
     },
     "type":"Array/string",
     "name":"Tags",
     "scope":"local"
  },
  {  
     "value":{  
        "string":{  
           "value":"subscribed"
        }
     },
     "type":"string",
     "name":"Error",
     "scope":"local"
  }
]
}
```

I have created following classes to bind the JSON

```
 public class OutputParameter
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
    public value value { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class value
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "array")]
    public array_ array_ { get; set; }
}

public class array_
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "elements")]
    public element[] element { get; set; }
}

public class element
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

I don't get any error while i'm deserializing it. Also i can navigate through easily.

but when i,m trying to get the value of element[n] (output_parameters[0].value.array_.element[0].value). it returns null.

What is the problem here ?

NOTE : I Just need few values to be taken from JSON. For example I don't need values like 
         "type":"string",
         "name":"Error",
         "scope":"local"
That's why i created C# classes like this.

Comment: shouldn't you look for "output_parameters[0].value.array_.element[0].string.value"?

Comment: Try using http://json2csharp.com/ for generating the C# classes from JSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Class should look like this since `output-parameters` is a array `[` and it might contain more values or list so create a `Rootobject` which contains List of output-parameters.

Now `output-parameters` not only contains `value` and `name` whereas it also contains. `type` and `scope` at the same hierarchy.

You have no declaration for node called `string` which is called here as `SomeString` and `SomeString1`

Your class Value also contains `string` which is denoted here as `SomeString1`

```
public class Rootobject
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "output-parameters")]
    public List<OutputParameters> outputparameters { get; set; }
}
public class OutputParameters
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
    public SomeValue value { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "type")]
    public string type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "scope")]
    public string scope { get; set; }
}
public class SomeValue
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "array")]
    public SomeArray array { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "string")]
    public SomeString1 _string { get; set; }
}
public class SomeArray
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "elements")]
    public List<SomeElement> elements { get; set; }
}
public class SomeElement
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "string")]
    public SomeString _string { get; set; }
}
public class SomeString
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
    public string value { get; set; }
}
public class SomeString1
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "value")]
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Then you should deserialize it using the following code

```
Rootobject ro = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(jsonstr);
Console.WriteLine(ro.outputparameters[0].value.array.elements[0]._string.value);
```

Screenshot which shows the value has been extracted

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: And public properties should be in PascalCase

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer: This is not necessary whereas it is one of the standard of naming conventions.

Comment: This also says the same thing .. Value is null :(

Comment: Now you need to update or edit the code of deserialization.

Comment: Please check the note i added :) ... I have checked by adding class call "string" ....     public class element
    {
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "string")]
        public string value { get; set; }
    }........... but this returns an error saying no tag found with the name "string"

Comment: Please remove your classes and replace it with the classes I have given as it is exactly. then see if you face any problem. Lemme show you the screenshot it works here

Answer (score 0):

According to the offcical microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-8-0), "The web default naming policy is camel case."

```
    JsonSerializerOptions options = new(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web)
    {
        WriteIndented = true
    };
```

In .NET 8, one can specify the naming policy that JSON can use when serializing/Decerializing

```
var test  = new HttpResponseMessage
{
    Content = JsonContent.Create(jsonBody, options: new JsonSerializerOptions { DictionaryKeyPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase }),
    StatusCode = httpStatusCode
};
```