# JSON Deserializing Returns Null for Sub List

Tags: c#, json

I'm attempting to deserialize the following json:

```
{"PatientNameID":{"ID":514,"Name":{"First":"Laura","Middle":"X","Last":"Coelho","Suffix":"","Full":"Laura X Coelho","Preferred":""}},"PatientNumber":"254","ChartNumber":"254","Gender":{"LookupType":"Gender","Code":"F","Description":"Female","Order":1,"Active":true,"AlternateCodes":null},"DOB":"4/9/1953","PhoneNumber":"3521029496","SSN":"*****0161"}
```

This is the class and subclasses into which I'm trying to deserialize the above JSON:

```
public class PatientList3
{
    public Pat PatientNameID { get; set; }
    public string PatientNumber { get; set; }
    public string ChartNumber { get; set; }
    public Gender2 Gender { get; set; }
    public string DOB { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string SSN { get; set; }
}

public class Pat
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public PtName Name { get; set; }
}

public class PtName
{
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Middle { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }
    public string Suffix { get; set; }
    public string Full { get; set; }
    public string Preferred { get; set; }
}

public class Gender2
{
    string LookupType { get; set; }
    string Code { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
    int Order { get; set; }
    bool Active { get; set; }
    List<AlternateCodes> AlternateCodes { get; set; }
}

public class AlternateCodes
{
    string Code { get; set; }
    string Description { get; set; }
    string CodeSystem { get; set; }
    string CodeSystemName { get; set; }
}
```

Everything goes well when I deserialize it except all of the values in the Gender2 class are null.

I've referred to the following two posts for answers but nothing seems to be doing to trick.

- [JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JsonString) returning all Properties<T> as Null](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/4d766a28-ff38-477f-8abf-48ed01f74cd2/jsonconvertdeserializeobjecttjsonstring-returning-all-propertiest-as-null?forum=wpdevelop)
- [DeSerializing JSON returns null C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40801494/deserializing-json-returns-null-c-sharp)

Comment: Fix the properties that are not public!

Comment: @cleftheris thanks, feel pretty dumb over looking that.

Comment: @w-harr glad it worked out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix the properties on `Gender2` & `AlternateCodes` they are not public! The deserializer will not be able to find your any of your properties so that is probably the reason this fails to populate.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with access modifiers of properties `Gender2` and `AlternateCodes` class, default access modifiers for properties is `private`. You should change it to:

```
public class Gender2
{
    public string LookupType { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public List<AlternateCodes> AlternateCodes { get; set; }
}

public class AlternateCodes
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string CodeSystem { get; set; }
    public string CodeSystemName { get; set; }
}
```

After setting properties to `public` it deserializes successfully:

[image]